# Update with SUM in Same SQL Table with Row Wise

Tags: sql-server

I want to update SUM in same SQL server table based on project id, SKU, Channel.

e.g. Channel 1 for PR1 Total SKU = SUM(SKU1,SKU2) from Channel1

e.g. Channel 2 for PR1 Total SKU = SUM(SKU1,SKU2) from Channel2

My TableA

```
id | Channel        | SKU       |  Project_id | Column1 | Column2
------------------------------------------------------------------
1    Channel 1        Total SKU      PR1          **10**    **10**      
2    Channel 2        Total SKU      PR1          **25**    **35**          
3    Channel 1        SKU1           PR1            5         5          
4    Channel 2        SKU1           PR1            15        15  
5    Channel 1        SKU2           PR1            5        5         
6    Channel 2        SKU2           PR1            10        20         
7    Channel 1        SKU1           PR2            30        50
8    Channel 2        SKU1           PR2            15        25         
9    Channel 1        SKU2           PR2            15        25 
10   Channel 2        SKU2           PR2            15        25
11   Channel 1        Total SKU      PR2          **45**        **75**
12   Channel 2        Total SKU      PR2          **30**        **50**
```

I am trying below solution but it is not working

```
;with cte_total
(
 select project_id, sum(column1) [c1total], sum(column2) [c2total], sum(column3) [c3total]
 from TableA
 where channel <> 'Channel'
 group by project_id, SKU
) 
update t
set column1 = c1Total, column2 = c2total, column3 = c3total
from TableA t
inner join cte_total ct ON (ct.project_id = t.project_id)
where t.chanel = 'Channel', SKU
```

Comment: I see a couple of issues here. This `where channel <> 'Channel'` will always be true looking at the data above. `where t.chanel = 'Channel', SKU` This will never be false and I'm not sure what the `, SKU` means here. And it looks like `t.chanel` is misspelled.

Answer (score 0):

For the life of me I cannot figure out why you're taking this approach, but nonetheless, you've asked.

Here's a simple example that should get you moving in your request. You can run the following in an SSMS query window.

```
-- Replicate TableA example.
DECLARE @TableA TABLE (
    id INT, Channel VARCHAR(20), SKU VARCHAR(20), Project_id VARCHAR(3), Column1 INT, Column2 INT
);

-- Insert example data.
INSERT INTO @TableA ( id, Channel, SKU, Project_id, Column1, Column2 ) 
VALUES
    ( 1 , 'Channel 1', 'Total SKU', 'PR1', 0, 0 ),    
    ( 2 , 'Channel 2', 'Total SKU', 'PR1', 0, 0 ),       
    ( 3 , 'Channel 1', 'SKU1', 'PR1', 5, 5  ),         
    ( 4 , 'Channel 2', 'SKU1', 'PR1', 15, 15 ),  
    ( 5 , 'Channel 1', 'SKU2', 'PR1', 5,  5  ),       
    ( 6 , 'Channel 2', 'SKU2', 'PR1', 10, 20 ),         
    ( 7 , 'Channel 1', 'SKU1', 'PR2', 30, 50 ),
    ( 8 , 'Channel 2', 'SKU1', 'PR2', 15, 25 ),         
    ( 9 , 'Channel 1', 'SKU2', 'PR2', 15, 25 ), 
    ( 10, 'Channel 2', 'SKU2', 'PR2', 15, 25 ),
    ( 11, 'Channel 1', 'Total SKU', 'PR2', 0, 0 ),
    ( 12, 'Channel 2', 'Total SKU', 'PR2', 0, 0 );

-- Update Channel totals for each Project id within the same table.
UPDATE @TableA
SET
    Column1 = ISNULL ( Totals.SumCol1, 0 ),
    Column2 = ISNULL ( Totals.SumCol2, 0 )
FROM @TableA AS TableA
OUTER APPLY (

    SELECT
        SUM ( n.Column1 ) AS SumCol1, SUM ( n.Column2 ) AS SumCol2
    FROM @TableA AS n
    WHERE 
        n.SKU <> 'Total SKU'
        AND n.Channel = TableA.Channel
        AND n.Project_id = TableA.Project_id

) AS Totals
WHERE
    TableA.SKU = 'Total SKU';

-- Show the updated resultset.
SELECT * FROM @TableA ORDER BY id;
```

Ending resultset:

```
+----+-----------+-----------+------------+---------+---------+
| id |  Channel  |    SKU    | Project_id | Column1 | Column2 |
+----+-----------+-----------+------------+---------+---------+
|  1 | Channel 1 | Total SKU | PR1        |      10 |      10 |
|  2 | Channel 2 | Total SKU | PR1        |      25 |      35 |
|  3 | Channel 1 | SKU1      | PR1        |       5 |       5 |
|  4 | Channel 2 | SKU1      | PR1        |      15 |      15 |
|  5 | Channel 1 | SKU2      | PR1        |       5 |       5 |
|  6 | Channel 2 | SKU2      | PR1        |      10 |      20 |
|  7 | Channel 1 | SKU1      | PR2        |      30 |      50 |
|  8 | Channel 2 | SKU1      | PR2        |      15 |      25 |
|  9 | Channel 1 | SKU2      | PR2        |      15 |      25 |
| 10 | Channel 2 | SKU2      | PR2        |      15 |      25 |
| 11 | Channel 1 | Total SKU | PR2        |      45 |      75 |
| 12 | Channel 2 | Total SKU | PR2        |      30 |      50 |
+----+-----------+-----------+------------+---------+---------+
```